# php - how to return every minute between 2 datetime in 2d array

Tags: php, datetime, multidimensional-array

can i get date time every minute in 2d array?i'm a beginner php developer.hope sme one can tell or share any idea.

let say my input as:

```
$startdate = 2013/7/01;
$enddate = 2013/7/02;
```

how can i have function as :

```
getMinuteRange($startdate, $enddate );
```

and i need the output of the function as:

```
Array (   
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 01/7/2013
        [1] => 12.00 a.m

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 01/7/2013
        [1] => 12.01 a.m

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 01/7/2013
        [1] => 12.03 a.m

    )
.
.
.

[2879] => Array
    (
        [0] => 02/7/2013
        [1] => 11.59 p.m

    )
```

)

Comment: see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you... it get the timestamp for the start and end timestamp and walks from one to the other incrementing by 60 seconds.

```
$startTime = "2013/07/01";
$endTime = "2013/07/02";

$startTS = strtotime($startTime);
$endTS = strtotime("tomorrow", strtotime($endTime));
$results = array();    
for($x = $startTS; $x<$endTS; $x+=60){ 
     $results[] = array(date("d/m/Y", $x), date("h.i a", $x));
}
if ($x != $endTS){
     $results[] = array(date("d/m/Y", $endTS), date("h.i a", $endTS));
}

print_r($results);
```

Comment: i just noticed those code will give date until 12.59pm on 1/7/2013.how i can adjust the code so if i choose start on 1/7/2013 and end 2/7/2013 so i get until 12.59pm on 2/7/2013 means 2880 minute(2 days time).

Comment: change `$endTS = strtotime($endTime);` to `echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("tomorrow", strtotime($endTime)));`

Comment: @zira Answer updated to reflect requested behavior

Answer (score 3):

```
$begin = new DateTime('2013/07/01');
$end = new DateTime('2013/07/02');

$interval = new DateInterval('PT1M');//1 minute
$periods = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end, DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE);

$arr = iterator_to_array($periods);
print_r($arr);
```

That gives you an array of `DateTime` objects. you can use `dateTime->format()` to format the time strings how you prefer.

Comment: notice this code only work when phpversion >= 5.3.0